# A fiber issue with `autoload`: `fiber called across stack rewinding barrier (FiberError)`

Tags: ruby, fiber, em-synchrony

We are using fiber with eventmachine (em-synchrony) in our production
env for quite a long time, and it works very well. We use the outdated
ruby 1.9.3 and ActiveRecord 3.x for over 2 years. We are migrating those
two big parts to the latest versions.

When trying to upgrade ruby to the latest, we got an exception `fiber
called across stack rewinding barrier (FiberError)` in 2.0+, but not in
1.9.3. Can you guys help us to figure out this problem?

Minimal sample:

test.rb

```
autoload :User, './user.rb'

f = Fiber.new do
  p User
end
f.resume
f.resume
```

user.rb

```
class User
end

Fiber.yield # This line is important
```

run

```
$ rvm 1.9.3,2.0,2.1 do sh -c 'echo ==== $RUBY_VERSION; ruby test.rb'
==== ruby-1.9.3-p551
User
==== ruby-2.0.0-p598
user.rb:4:in `yield': fiber called across stack rewinding barrier (FiberError)
    from user.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from test.rb:4:in `block in <main>'
==== ruby-2.1.5
user.rb:4:in `yield': fiber called across stack rewinding barrier (FiberError)
    from user.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from test.rb:4:in `block in <main>'
```

More sample codes are in this repo:

https://github.com/qqshfox/test_fiber

Any help would be appreciated!